# Error when getting a value inside an Object from Object array from a drop down in Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, for-loop, object, boolean

I am getting the selected values from a dropdown in angular through an event.

```
getSelectedValueList($event: any[]) {
        console.log($event);
        const ids = this.selectedIds($event);
        console.log(ids);
    }
```

In here My `console.log($event);` output is coming like this.

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 3045, name: "US", isSelected: true, isDefault: false} 
1: {id: 2755, name: "INDIA", isSelected: false, isDefault: false}
2: {id: 0, name: "None", isSelected: true, isDefault: false}
length: 3
```

This is my  `selectedIds` method.

```
selectedIds(list): any[] {
        console.log(list);
        console.log(list[2].isDefault);
        const codeList: any[] = [];
        for (const element of list) {
            console.log(element);
            if (element.isSelected) {
                codeList.push(element.id);
            }
        }
        console.log(codeList);
        return codeList;
    }
```

Here also my `console.log(list);` output coming like this as above like this.

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 3045, name: "US", isSelected: true, isDefault: false} 
1: {id: 2755, name: "INDIA", isSelected: false, isDefault: false}
2: {id: 0, name: "None", isSelected: true, isDefault: false}
length: 3
```

But if i `console.log(element);`  it gives each output like this. The `isSelected: true` thing that has coming in `console.log(list);`  is showing as false.

```
 {id: 3045, name: "US", isSelected: false, isDefault: false}
 {id: 2755, name: "INDIA", isSelected: false, isDefault: false}
 {id: 0, name: "None", isSelected: false, isDefault: false}
```

What is the problem here? I could n't find?

Comment: Are they unselected in the UI when you inspect your log? `console.log(myObject)` will dynamically update itself if the underlying value of `myObject` changes, even if there are hours separating the log and your inspection of the log. To get around this, try `console.log({...myObject})` instead. This will log a clone of the object that is never going to be changed. I don't know if this is your issue, but it's something you might consider.

Comment: In the Ui they are not unselected

Comment: @user1713450 I `console.log({...myObject})` This is also gives the same output as above

Comment: I don't think this is related to the issue, but FYI you can make your `selectedIds` function much simpler: `selectedIds(list): number[] { return list.filter(element => element.isSelected).map(element => element.id); }`